# Unwanted margin between 2 menu items header website (on some pages)

Tags: php, css, header, responsive, margin

I am updating my website

-- WEBSITE --

A web developer made it years an ago.

Now I put an SSL Encryption on the website. But after that change, it seems there is an unwanted margin in the header on some pages.

I can't seem to find out where it's coming from. [Image: unwanted margin between header menu items][1]

My screen resolution is: 1920 x 1080

Anybody knows how to solve this?

I tried already to use different widths for the menu items and margins.
But I think I am doing something wrong..

Comment: Add `background-size: cover` to the `li` elements. From MDN: `cover` - Scales the image as large as possible to fill the container, stretching the image if necessary.

Comment: Hi, I checked it in chrome and in firefox. I can't see the black margin as seen in your image.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm seeing when I click the link:

[image]

I think it possibly has something to do with just your screen resolution, but I'm not an expert. I know I've had plenty of experiences were if I scroll too fast or I resize the viewport, I get black lines in between items that flicker and then disappear, so it could be something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! Maybe it's indeed my pc settings. 
Good to see that the website is properly showing on your computer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for responding.

I found the solution in  siva - abc's answer.

I added 'background-size: cover' to the list items in the CSS classes and now the problem is solved!

Thanks all!